# TortoiseSVN/VisualSVN Server version number in filename

Tags: version-control, ms-word, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I've just set up a VisualSVN server at work for document control and we are using TortoiseSVN clients. The documents are mainly in .docx format. I was wondering if there's any way to get the version number to automatically update in the filename and perhaps the footer of these documents?

e.g. filename (doesn't have to be exactly this) Important_Doc_rev_01.docx.

e.g. footer "Important document v.01. Last updated 19th May 2016."

Been messing around with the settings and Googling like a madman but I can't seem to find a working solution. Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: May I ask why you want this?  Does VisualSVN not provide a way to determine versioning of each file?

Comment: I asked the same question to my boss. He says that it's to prevent human error when updating filenames/footers. I said I'd look into it but wasn't hopeful. I know that some IDE's have built-in version control functionality and wondered if word had something similar. If it's not possible we can just drum it into the users to remember to update the filenames etc.

Comment: Oh, and as for your second question, it does through the repo browser but when actually accessing the documents after checking out/updating there doesn't appear to be a way to tell which version you're working on,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `*.docx` isn't plain-text, thus - you can't use SVN-keywords in document's body
2. Renaming files **in repository** is always (SIC!!!) hand-work and version-in-trailing-part-of-filename is *mauvais ton* and legacy "before-VCS" style
3. Some embedded macros exist in Word and can be (independently from rxternals VCS) used in documents

Comment: 1. Thanks
2. Could you please elaborate on this one?
3. Ah, so Word macros are the way to go, cheers. 

My rep is too low so can't give you an upvote but thank you kindly.

Comment: @I_GNU_it_all_along - 2 Extended: VCS use own methods for storing version-info data for all objects, change filename is *less* machine-friendly way of doing it. For any (even binary) versioned object VCS can provide it's revision anyway: see `svn help info`